# Is automatic horizontal scaling possible in Cloud Native PostgreSQL deployed in Kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I'm using Cloud Native PostgreSQL in AKS, it's a fantastic product!
So I have deployed the PostgreSQL cluster, but could not figure out a way to set up an automatic horizontal scaling for the cluster pods. Is there any way to achieve the same apart from increasing the instance count in the cluster spec manually?

Operator config: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cloudnative-pg/cloudnative-pg/main/releases/cnpg-1.15.0.yaml

I have referred the following document:
https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/postgres_for_kubernetes/latest/replication/